# How to increase video upload quota on Youtube API?

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

We are a UA agency and we are building an internal tool to automatically upload videos on YouTube in order to then use these videos in our Google Ads App Campaigns. However, we are currently limited to uploading 6 videos through YouTube API per day which is way too low compared to our needs. We followed the process to request a quota increase. However, we can't  go through as our system is internal so Google can't check its use or purpose. We would like to get in touch with someone to whom we can explain the issue.

Cheers,
Matthieu

Comment: By *bandwidth* you mean [quota](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/getting-started#quota) correct? (In "We followed the process to request more bandwidth. However, we can't go through as our system is internal so Google can't check its use or purpose.")

Comment: Indeed I meant quota for uploading videos through YouTube API. I'll edit original message, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

By default, YouTube allows video uploads that are up to 15 minutes long. If you try to upload videos longer than 15 minutes, the upload will fail. This is a YouTube limitation rather than a Brightcove limitation.

To upload longer videos to YouTube, you need to verify your account with YouTube:

Open the YouTube upload page at https://www.youtube.com/upload.
Click Increase your limit link at the bottom of the page.

[image]

Note: If you can't find the Increase your limit link, it's possible that you may already be able to upload long videos. Check the Longer videos section in your YouTube Account Features page to check if the feature has already been enabled.

[image]

Follow the steps to verify your account with a mobile phone.
[image]

When you receive a text message from YouTube in response, enter the verification code from the text message and click Submit.
[image]

YouTube will then confirm when your YouTube account has been activated for longer uploads. From this point, any videos longer than 15 minutes in your Video Cloud account will be synced to YouTube.

Comment: Thanks Muhammad, but here we are trying to upload more than 6 videos a day (which are usually shorter than 20sec), this is the limit we are looking to increase.

Comment: Please go to YouTube Studio ---> Settting ---> Feature eligibility .

And enable all 3 features 1- Standard feature, 2- Intermediate feature and 3- Advance feature. If you're allowed to all these feature, you will never get video upload limit error message.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to apply for a quota extension, you can do so here: https://support.google.com/youtube/contact/yt_api_form?hl=en